# Pagination not displaying on a web page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Hi everyone I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP.

I'm trying to create pagination on one of my pages, but my code doesn't display the pagination on the page for some reason.

view.php

```
 </head>
   <body>


            <h1>Answer</h1>
            <?php if (isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>

      <div = 'container'>


          <?php 
          if (isset($pagination))
            {
            echo $pagination;
            } 
           ?>

          <ul>
           <h1><?php  echo  $row->question; ?></h1>
           <li><?php  echo  $row->answer1; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer2; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer3; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer4; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer5; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer6; ?></li>
          <ul>

       </div>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php else : ?>
          <h2>no records were returned</h2>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

control.php

```
<?php

class Survey extends CI_Controller{

function index()
{
          $data = array(
         'question' => $this->input->post('question'),
          'answer1' => $this->input->post('answer1'),
          'answer2' => $this->input->post('answer2'),
          'answer3' => $this->input->post('answer3'),
          'answer4' => $this->input->post('answer4'),
          'answer5' => $this->input->post('answer5'),
          'answer6' => $this->input->post('answer6'),
           );


           if($query = $this->membership_model->get_records())
           {
               $data['records'] = $query;
           }

           $this->load->view('survey_view', $data);

           }

//pagination
        function page()
           {

            $this->load->library('pagination');


            $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/admin/index.php/survey/index';
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('save_survey')->num_rows();
            $config['per_page'] = 1;
            $config['num_links'] =10;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $data['records'] = $this->db-get('save_survey', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $this->load->view('survey_view', $data);

          }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `page()` is never called.

When you navigate to the controller then the default `index()` function will be triggered. And in that function there is no call to `page();` method.

I never used the pagination stuff of CI before, but to include your pagination code (`page()`) in the `index()` method, you can do it like this (I removed the view from the page method):

```
class Survay extends CI_Controller{
    function index() {
        $data = array(
            'question' => $this->input->post('question'),
            'answer1' => $this->input->post('answer1'),
            'answer2' => $this->input->post('answer2'),
            'answer3' => $this->input->post('answer3'),
            'answer4' => $this->input->post('answer4'),
            'answer5' => $this->input->post('answer5'),
            'answer6' => $this->input->post('answer6'),
        );


        if($query = $this->membership_model->get_records()) {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }

        //call your page method and set the pagination variables to this object
        $this->page();

        //show the view
        $this->load->view('survay_view', $data);
    }

    //pagination ONLY sets the pagination variables
    function page() {
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/admin/index.php/survay/index';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('save_survay')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->db-get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for ur help i did what u said but as soon as i called page method an error poped up  "Call to undefined function get()" any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: The get method is from the db class. Did you autoload the database library (config-->autoload.php)? If not, then you need to load it before using it `$this->load->database();`.

Comment: yes i did tnx for ur help u saved me a lot of time :) but now i am getting a diffrent error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/survay_view.php

Line Number: 31
do u have any idea what is causing this error ? :)

Comment: its this line <h1><?php  echo  $row->question; ?></h1>

Comment: No problem. The error states that you are trying to access an property of the object row that doesn't exists. You can see whats in the row object by using an `var_dump($row);` before that h1 line.

Comment: wehen i used the var_dump($row); a line came up saying "resource(29, mysql link persistent" can u explain what it means ? tnx

Comment: No i can't say what that error is. Var dump only shows what's in the object. You filled the records variable with the results of the db. So it has to be an array with the field names as index. If not, then you should check your db query (the $this->db->get())